# Difference between .Net 2.0 and .Net 4.0 current directory

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, .net-2.0, .net-4.5

As outlined earlier, ([Running .Net 2.0 executable in .Net 4.0 program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16859200/running-net-2-0-executable-in-net-4-0-program)) I was having problems running a .Net 2.0 exe from a .Net 4.0 program. I solved that program somewhat by installing .Net 2.0. Now the program can run properly under certain situations. Namely, if I work with files exclusively in the same directory as my program. What happens is the following:

1. User selects a file
2. .Net 2.0 exe acts on that file, creates a new file
3. .Net 2.0 exe acts on new file

This all works fine if the original file is in the same directory as the program (and the .Net 2.0 exe). The files created by the 2.0 exe are saved in that directory and all is good. However if the original file is NOT in the same directory as the program, the 2.0 exe creates the new file in the folder of the original file. This causes the program to crash, since it expects the new file to be in the same directory as the 2.0 exe. It's worth noting that this only happens in XP running .Net 2.0 and 4.0. On my main Windows 7 machine running .Net 4.5 this problem doesn't occur.

Here is the code where I call the 2.0 exe:

```
Process process = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = "/C 2.0EXE -i " + userFile + " -o " + resultsFile;
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
startInfo.WorkingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
```

Is there some obvious solution I'm missing? Preferably not something involving modifying the path, since as I plan to distribute this application, I don't want to make the end user do that.

Edit: Even when I force the working directory to be some constant directory (instead of Environment.CurrentDirectory), it still won't exactly work. Now it saves the file in the correct location (step 2), but the 2.0 exe then looks for the new file in the same folder as the original file (i.e. step 3 fails). Again this only happens on the XP machine running .Net 4.0 and 2.0.

Comment: Maybe you should check the current directory (display it) before calling the .Net 2.0 exe.

Comment: Using Environment.CurrentDirectory is *much* too risky.  It has the typical problem of a global variable, it can change without you knowing about it.  As in step #1 when you, say, use OpenFileDialog to allow the user to select the file.  You'll need to get rid of this and always pick a known directory.  One that you *know* that this program is compatible with.

Comment: @Medinoc, yes in fact it in the wrong directory.

Comment: @HansPassant: yeah, I guess Environment.Current directory is changing in this case.

Comment: I guess the main thing I'm confused with is the different behavior on the 2 platforms.